# IntelliJ menu bar not responding

Tags: intellij-idea, macos-mojave

None of the top **menu actions** is responding (from 'File' to 'Help').
[image]

I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Ultimate Edition), build #IU-183.4284.148** on **macOS Mojave version 10.14** via the jetbrains toolbox. I tried restarting the computer and intellij, nothing helps.
I also tried to find the intellij log files stored somewhere, but I can't find it, even with the help of jetbrains documentation [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519).
I am running out of ideas.

Has anyone encountered the same issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What JVM do you [run IDE under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879)? Make sure you are using bundled JDK.

Comment: For some reason I wasn't using a bundled boot JDK. That fixes the problem :) Thanks a lot